# For $n \in Z^{\geq 0}$, define $g_n = 2^{2^n} + 1$. Show that $g_0\cdot g_1\cdots g_{n-1} = g_n -2$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, induction

> For $n \in Z^{\geq 0}$, define $g_n = 2^{2^n} + 1$. Show that $g_0\cdot g_1\cdots g_{n-1} = g_n -2$ for all $n \in Z^+$.

I thought that this could be proved using induction, but then the base case wouldn't work since for n=0, there would be nothing on the left hand side of the equation. Is there a way to prove this algebraically or otherwise?

Comment: ah yes, thank you! I have looked through the responses for this post, though and have not found any that really answer my question unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

The base case, for $n=1$, is $g_0 = g_1-2$ or $2^1+1 = 2^2+1-2$ or $3 = 5-2$.

From this,
you can use induction.

Comment: Okay thank you, this makes sense! So when I use the induction step, should I be showing that $ g_0⋅g_1⋯g_{n−1}⋅g_n =g_{n+1}-2 $ ?

Comment: Yep. And remember that the $n$ is two levels up, and that $2^{2^{n+1}} = (2^{2^n})^2$.